# Error while pulling from remote Git repository

Tags: git, gitlab, tortoisegit

Error specification:

> cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/m2I2/raju': unable to create lock file .git/refs/remotes/origin/m2I2/raju.lock; non-directory in the way

[image: Error displayed by Tortoise Git]

Everything was working fine, but after my last push I am continuously facing this issue while pushing.

Comment: So do you get the error from pushing or pulling? Title and question content do not match.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a branch `m2i2`, `M2I2` or `M2i2` in origin and also a branch `m2I2/raju`. As you are pulling to Windows which is case insensitive you get a name clash, as the `fetch` tries to create a file `raju.lock` in the directory `m2I2` while there is already a file `m2i2`, `M2I2` or `M2i2` for the remote branch present and thus cannot create the directory `m2I2` as those are the same name on Windows.

To verify this, please execute `git ls-remote origin '*m2i2*' '*M2I2*' '*M2i2*' '*m2I2*'` and add its output to your question if you don't get it sorted yourself. And please don't use screenshots for textual output, but paste it as text, prefixed by four spaces.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to us.  Two git branches differed only by case, and we ran into the "non-directory in the way" error on our (Windows) build server.  Removing one of the branches fixed the problem.